# Refractive index as a function of concentration of sugar solution and wavelength of light

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

We recently performed an experiment with the idea to find refractive index of medium (water) as a function of wavelength of light. We then added some sugar to see how the refractive index changes with concentration of sugar solution. We got the following graphs.

[image]

[image]

Are the relationships actually linear? Or are these just limiting cases? 
Can someone shed some intuition on why the graph is in the way it is?

Comment: You seem to be missing uncertainty bars on your data points ;-). Those will tell you a lot about how much you can trust that linear dependence.

Comment: For the relation $n=f(\lambda)$, Cauchy's law may be what you're looking for ($n = A + \frac{B}{\lambda^2} + \dots$). For the relation $n = f(c)$, you may see [this paper](http://ku.edu.np/kuset/second_issue/o2/DEEPAK%20SUBEDI.pdf).

Comment: @Spirine: Thank you for the Cauchy's law. But that paper doesn't have any explanation on why its linear.

Comment: The graph is approximately hyperbolic. Hyperbola graphs are approximately linear near the asymptotes.

Comment: @Yashas That's a fairly misleading characterization, I should think. Cauchy's law is a useful approximation in some regimes but nothing more than that, and once you get to where it would get properly 'hyperbolic', you find that the model breaks down. Instead, a much more useful characterization is as a sum of Lorentz oscillators (which are also approximately linear when you're far enough from the resonance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the dependence on the sugar concentration you do expect from first principles (at least at low saturations) that the dependence will be linear, since the electric susceptibility $\chi$ is essentially the molecular polarizability $\alpha$ of each contributing species times the number density of said species.

---

As far as the wavelength dependence goes, it's not fully linear but it's a good approximation over that range. (And, as I mentioned in the comments, your data looks vaguely linear but once you put in the error bars and do a full uncertainty analysis, you're likely to find that it's much more consistent with a variety of non-linear behaviours than it looks from your graph.) [This website](https://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=main&book=H2O&page=Kedenburg) has some reasonable-looking data, and this is backed up in the literature:

> Refractive Index of Water and Its Dependence on Wavelength, Temperature, and Density. I. Thormählen, J. Straub, and U. Grigull. [*J. Phys. Chem. Ref. Data* **14**, 933 (1985)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.555743), [NIST eprint](https://srd.nist.gov/JPCRD/jpcrd282.pdf).

In particular, if you look for wavelengths just a bit above and below that range, you get something much more illuminating,

[image]

i.e. the downward slant comes because the visible range is sandwiched between two resonances, which themselves can be well described using the [Lorentz oscillator model](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-007-electromagnetic-energy-from-motors-to-lasers-spring-2011/readings/MIT6_007S11_lorentz.pdf).